# Long exact sequence too long

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

Is there any way to fit the following long exact sequence in normal text width without making it too ugly?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep = tiny]
 \cdots \arrow[r] &H_{k + 1}(X^{(n)}, X^{(n - 1)}) \arrow[r] & H_k(X^{(n - 1)}, A) \arrow[r]  &  H_k(X^{(n)}, A)\arrow[r] & H_k(X^{(n)}, X^{(n - 1)}) \arrow[r]& \cdots 
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

I have thought about breaking it into two lines, but the length of the arrow at the end (the ones that come out from "\cdots") is way too short.

```
\documentclass[draft]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
 \[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep = tiny, row sep = tiny]
 \cdots \arrow[r] &H_{k + 1}(X^{(n)}, X^{(n - 1)}) \arrow[r] & H_k(X^{(n - 1)}, A) \arrow[r]  & {}\\
 \arrow[r] & H_k(X^{(n)}, A)\arrow[r] & H_k(X^{(n)}, X^{(n - 1)}) \arrow[r]& \cdots
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

Ideally I would want to shink the above sequence enough so that it would looks good in the numerate environment.

I am looking for an answer using tikz-cd, which I assume is the package most textbooks use, but I would happily accept an answer not using tikz-cd if it produce better effects.

Comment: Hi, look enough nice for you to change     \arrow[r] with      \longrightarrow?

Comment: Do you really need tikz-cd for an exact sequence?

Comment: @Colo I also thought about that, but if the diagram has two lines and is at the end of a page, wouldn't the diagram split onto two pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you don't need any alignment points here I'm not sure a CD notation helps, I split it over two lines just using `multline`

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{multline*}
 \cdots \rightarrow H_{k + 1}(X^{(n)}, X^{(n - 1)}) \rightarrow H_k(X^{(n - 1)}, A)\\ \rightarrow
  H_k(X^{(n)}, A)\rightarrow H_k(X^{(n)}, X^{(n - 1)}) \rightarrow \cdots 
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks wonderful! Just curious, is it possible to create a vertical arrow in the multline environment?

Comment: er well you can use `\uparrow` as in any math, but as I said in the opening line this gives up alignment so positioning the `\uparrow` might be tricky.... @Jpw5567